# transport equation interpretation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimal-transport, transport-equation

**Premise:** Theorem 5.34 from the book *"Topics in Optimal Transportation"*

Let $X$ be $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $(T_t)_{0\leq t\leq T_{*}}$ be a locally Lipschitz family of diffeomorphisms in $X$, with $T_{0}=Id,$ and let $v=v(t,x)$ be the velocity field associated with trajectories $(T_{t})$. Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $X$, and $\rho_t=T_t\#\mu.$ Then, $\rho_t=\rho(t,\cdot)$ is the unique solution of the linear transport equation

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+ \triangledown \cdot (\rho v)=0,\quad 0<t<T_*\ with \ \rho_0=\mu$$

in $C([0,T_*);P(X)),$ where $P(X)$ is equipped with weak topology.

**Question:** 1) Assuming $d\rho_{t}(x)=f_{t}(x)dx$, How to write equation satisfied by $f_{t}$ from given equation in theorem?
2) How to interpret derivative and divergence operation in equation given that $\rho$ is a measure?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can find the definition of a distributional solution to the continuity equation [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456284/continuity-equation-partial-t-mu-t-operatornamediv-v-t-mu-t-0-are-the).